# How to capture input parameter in jasper server?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I want to capture input parameter values in jasper server and need to display those parameter in jasper server log file.

1. In coding I am not passing parameters and reports
2. Just calling jasper server report url to display report in my application.
3. Jasper server version 6.1
4. I need to display those log in below path.

   ```
   C:\Jaspersoft_server_latest\jasperreports-server-cp-6.1.0\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\WEB-INF\logs
   ```

Input parameters of report:
 [image]

Comment: So, you want to create a report to look into the logs files? If you don't pass parameters, which parameters do you want to capture?

Comment: parameter 1. starting date  :05-09-2016    parameter 2 : ending date :15-09-2016

Comment: Sorry, still not understanding: Do you want to create a report which looks at the log files? Do you have it already? What do you mean by "In coding I am not passing parameters and reports"?

Comment: If I understand @Mani correctly then he needs to print the value entered by a user in input controls of a report to the jasperserver log file. If this is what you are asking for then for this I used Scriptlets. Actually scriptlets are pretty interesting, as you can not only just log the input items but also do input validation, fancy calculations, etc. If this is what you are looking for then reply in comment and I can write an answer for you with an example.

Comment: Hi Siddharth  you are correct  please share the answer with example.

Comment: 1. Ya  i need to create log file

Comment: Hi  tobi  :    1. Ya  i need to create log file   2. I want to display below information in   in jasper server log    3.user name ,report name, inputs range .   4.In coding means :  inside my java application not passing parameters for report your  information because if i use parameter in java application i can catch the all information ( user name,report name, inputs) using java code easily using  application  log.

Comment: @Mani I will try to add the answer sometime today. And since you did not tag me in your reply so I did not get a notification that you replied. Kindly do that the next time.

Comment: @Siddharth  please help on this.

Comment: @Mani sorry for I have busy due to which I have not been able to post the answer. But I will do it soon.

Comment: @Siddharth ..okay thanks..

Comment: @Siddharth  I am waiting for your answer please post as soon as possible

Comment: @Mani have you done, could you please share the code.